# Xpath doesn't find anything

Tags: html, python-2.7, xpath

I have this webiste : http://directory.ccnecommunity.org/reports/rptAccreditedPrograms_New.asp?sort=institution

Each university is separated with a line. I want to get the dates under Bacalaureat, Master's and Doctor of Nursing Practice of each university.

My XPATH :

`/table[@width="95%" and @align="center" and @class="center"]
//table[@width="260px"]/tr/td[@style="width: 100%;"]/text()'`

it returns an empty list.

As you see between the root table and the second there are a lot of other elements so I did a **double slash** `//`.

P.S. I do this from root because I would like to retrieve the data by index :

`/table[@width="95%" and @align="center" and @class="center"][1]
//table[@width="260px"]/tr/td[@style="width: 100%;"]/text()'`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the dates under Bacalaureat, Master's and Doctor of Nursing Practice of each university.

Try this xpath for Bacalaureat:

```
//tr/td[span="Baccalaureate"]
```

For Master's try:

```
//tr/td[contains(span,"Master")]
```

And for Doctor of Nursing Practice"

```
 //tr/td[span="Doctor of Nursing Practice"]
```

And all together:

```
//tr/td[span="Baccalaureate"] | //tr/td[contains(span,"Master")] | //tr/td[contains(span,"Master")]
```

Update:
To access each university with wonted data (here only with Baccalaureate and Master) by an index you may try:

```
(//tr[ td[span="Baccalaureate"] or td[contains(span,"Master")] ]/ancestor::tr[1])
[3]//tr/td[span="Baccalaureate" or contains(span,"Master")]/text()
```

Comment: you haven't understood me! I need the absolute path, you showed me the path for each of them individually from tr,td

Comment: Yes seem I do not understand you. Why do you think you need a absolute path? But in your xpath is a `tbody` missing. Try `$x('//table[@width="95%" and @align="center" and @class="center"]//table[@width="260px"]/tbody/tr/td[@style="width: 100%;"]/text()')`

Comment: It's not that tbody that's missing - it's smth else.

I need the absolute path for accessing each table by index. I'm telling this the 2nd time

Comment: If you use `$x( xapth )` for example in firefox console you wil seel that your xpaht returns (as you say) an empty  list if you add the `tbody` it will return a lot of dates.

Comment: hmmm... I do it from python, but anyways it doesn't work either even if I add the tbody..

Look at this question I asked not long ago :
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977369/xpath-html-with-a-lot-of-children/36977726#36977726)

There are a lot of sub-children in my html, and I don't have the power to access each ot them...

Comment: There seems to be something else going on (also in your other question).  You need to know how your DOM is build. Browser add a tbody to the html-DOM (if it is missing).  I do not know what python will do.

Comment: @CatalinBesleaga Have a look to the update ([3] is the index 3)