# XPATH - html with a lot of children

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping

Consider the html in the **page** variable.

How do I access the **td**s ?

I want to access them like `xpath("/table/tr/td/text())"`

I don't want to indicate the other **tr**s

Unfortunately this expression `xpath('.//table/tr/tr/tr/td/text()')` doesn't work either.

Python code:

```
import __future__
from lxml import html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>cv</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>table1 td1</td>
                    <td>table1 td2</td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>table2 td1</td>
                    <td>table2 td2</td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>table3 td1</td>
                    <td>table3 td2</td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = str(BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser'))
tree = html.fromstring(soup)

things = tree.xpath('.//table/tr/tr/tr/td/text()')

print(things)

for thing in things:
        print(thing)

print('That's all')
```

I want it from the root!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xpath `//td/text()`:

```
things = tree.xpath('//td/text()')
```

The `//td` stands for "find any `td` element in any depth.

Works for me.

## Printing `td` elements grouped per `table`:

```
doc = html.fromstring(page)
for table_elm in doc.xpath("//table"):
    print "another table"
    things = table_elm.xpath('.//td/text()')
    print(things)
```

Note, that in this case is the `.` in xpath significant.

Comment: Doesn't help me, I want it form the root!!!
Cause subsequently I'll acces the tds from each table index like :
`xpath("/table[1]/tr/td/text()")`

Comment: Whats about `xpath("/table[1]//td/text()")`

Comment: @hr_117 Ok, if output shall be grouped per table, then we do the xpath per table. See extended answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don'have to convert `BeautifulSoup` to `str`:

```
soup = str(BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser'))
```

You can use something like this:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
>>> for td in soup.find_all('td'):
...     print(td)
... 
<td>table1 td1</td>
<td>table1 td2</td>
<td>table2 td1</td>
<td>table2 td2</td>
<td>table3 td1</td>
<td>table3 td2</td>
```

Or, you can also use `print(td.text)` if you want the text inside the element.

Answer (score 1):

`tr` inside of `tr` is invalid HTML.

And this seems to be "fixed" by the `html.fromstring()` parser.

You can test this with this xpath:

```
things = tree.xpath('//table/tr/*')
```

And output with:

```
for thing in things:
   print(thing.tag)
```

Which generates:

```
td
td
td
td
td
```